# C# Fire Event Whenever Any Variable of Class Is Updated?

Tags: c#, class, events

I'd like to have it so that there is a function that is called anytime a variable inside my class is changed. I know I could do this with get-set variables but if I'd prefer not to set that up for every single variable in my class is there a better way?

Comment: @DanielAbouChleih: Not really a duplicate, as the accepted solution of that question was explicitly ruled out here (not that there would be any other way to go).

Comment: Standard issue "help me circumvent the language" question. Just because the question rules out the solution, does _not_ mean that the restriction is reasonable or applicable .

Comment: @Gusdor: As evidenced by the existence of two answers, the restriction is very much applicable (to the question).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper My use of 'applicable' referred to the absence of that language feature. Sorry for confusion. Both answers _correctly_ disregard the requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there's no better way.
You can use tools like PostSharp to make it easier for you, but you'll need properties.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such mechanism available. Writing to an instance variable is pretty much like directly writing some bytes at a given memory address, and there is no hook notifying you when that is done. That is exactly what properties with their getters and setters are there for.

Comment: To the OP, it is worth using visual studio _code snippets_ to do a lot of this code for you. It can be time consuming without.